# Old data not displayed in edit.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, crud

This is my `edit` method:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    // ...
    
    return view('admin.biodata.edit',
        [
            'title' => 'Edit Biodata',
            'active' => 'biodata',
            'majors' => Major::all(),
            'biodata' => $user
        ]
    );
}
```

#### `edit.blade.php`

```html
@extends('admin.adminDashboard.layouts.main')

@section('container')
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2"></div>
<h1>Edit Student</h1>
<div class="container">
    <form action="{{url('admin/biodata')}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $biodata->id }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" value="{{$biodata->name}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nrp">NRP</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nrp" name="nrp" placeholder="Enter NRP" value="{{$biodata->nrp}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="{{$biodata->email}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter address" value="{{$biodata->address}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="generation">Generation</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="generation" name="generation" placeholder="Enter generation" value="{{$biodata->generation}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="major">Major</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="major" name="major_id">
                @foreach ($majors as $major)
                <option value="{{$major->id}}">{{$major->nama_jurusan}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

@endsection
```

When I press the `edit` button from the `index` view, the old data is not displayed in the view `admin.biodata.edit`. I thought I have already passed the user data through the `biodata` variable.

Comment: Try to dd this varible dd($biodata) are they any values?

Comment: What do you mean "the old data"?

Comment: Does your `User` model have `nrp`, `address` and `generation` fields?  Use `dd($user)` in your `edit(User $user)` controller and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the value in the template with

```
value="{{old('name',$biodata->name)}}"
```